# Disk Usage in elasticsearch2.x vs elasticsearch 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch, diskspace

Hey I have recently upgraded from Elasticsearch 2.4 to Elasticsearch 7.2 and I was wondering that my index( 15 GB in 2.4 version ) I completely inserted the exact same index with same mapping, same number of documents, same replication and shards also but when I see the size in version 7.2 is 25GB and then I checked for few other indices I have in both new and older version, it turns out that the increase in size is pretty much around 40% for each index. So, I am missing something why is this increase in disk usage OR this is expected ( if the way ES internally stores data has changed in new version causing more space usage)?

Comment: How do you check disk space usage for the index?

Comment: I check it from Kibana Dashboard, it shows the size of each index in front of it.